# Detect expired password against Active Directory

Tags: asp.net

I have a website (asp.net) you authenticate against AD company. The authentication code I found in this great forum (I put it below). The problem is that if the user has the password expired, my code directly tells him is wrong and people get a little crazy.

I searched on google to detect this, but I find nothing.

Can you help? How I can know if the password is expired or must change? and if so how can the user change it?

Mi code:

Public Function usuarioYPassDM(tUsuario As String, tcontraseña As String) As Boolean

```
    Dim esError As String

    'primero ver si es un usuario de dm

    ' devolveremos true si son credenciales válidas, false si no

    Dim entrada As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry()

    entrada.Path = LDAP://SERVER******

    entrada.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure

    entrada.Username = tUsuario

    entrada.Password = tcontraseña

    Dim dsSystem As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(entrada, "(sAMAccountName=" & tUsuario & ")")

    Dim srSystem As SearchResult

    dsSystem.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree

    Try

        srSystem = dsSystem.FindOne()

        usuarioYPassDM = True

    Catch ex As Exception

        esError = ex.Message.ToString

        usuarioYPassDM = False

    End Try

End Function
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adpowershell/archive/2010/02/26/find-out-when-your-password-expires.aspx) is function that calculates the password expiration date of a user object given its samAccountName, security identifier or DistinguishedName.

Comment: The code in this function is scrip, I ned the code in asp.net. I' dont know "trastate" from script to asp.net.